# Assign a docID to each document in a folder

Tags: python

I have a folder of text files in a folder named Serverend and now i would like to assign some ID to each text files in this i used the code below

```
docID_list = [int(docID_string) for docID_string in os.listdir('Serverend')]
```

but i ended up with the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

can any one help me out

Comment: What do the filenames look like? I'm assuming they have non-numeric characters in them, which `int()` is unable to convert. try hashing them (`hashlib`) if that's the case.

Comment: Great thanks worked..

Answer (score 0):

The filenames you're listing in `os.listdir()` are strings with non-numeric characters in them. `int()` is unable to create integers based on those strings.

If you don't have a requirement for numeric IDs, consider just taking the md5 hash of the filename as a document ID:

```
import hashlib

docID_list = [hashlib.md5(docID_string).hexdigest() for docID_string in os.listdir('Serverend')]
```

(Added as answer based on my above comment.)